# Why does the pasta I make with my extruder always stick together?

Tags: pasta

I've tried a few times now to make pasta with my Kitchen Aid extruder and EVERY time it sticks together and tears when I try to separate the strands. What am I doing wrong?

I am new to homemade pasta and although I've tried several times I've never actually gotten an edible product. I started with 4 eggs 2 cups "pasta" flour but the dough didn't end up picking up all the flour. It wasn't sticky and I let it rest about 30 minutes before putting it in the extruder.

Comment: More details and some photos please

Comment: Usual reasons are dough too wet, not kneaded enough. For fine pasta try a hair dryer blowing perpendicular to exit point

Comment: Do you have a food processor?

Answer (score 6):

Your dough is too wet.

Four eggs is a lot for 2 cups flour - the [KPEXTA user guide](http://pastamakercentral.com/content/user_manuals/KitchenAid-KPEXTA-User-Manual.pdf) suggests 4 eggs + 1 tbsp water for 3-1/2 cups flour. Assuming you're using the mixer to mix the dough, it should be crumbly and not form a ball, but it should hold together when you pick some up and squeeze it in your hand. If you have a kitchen scale handy a typical egg pasta ratio is one large egg (about 1/4 cup) per 100 grams flour.